# How do I calculate primitive roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Supposing we are in $\mathbb{Z}_{17}$, how do I calculate the primitive roots of this group under multiplication?

My professor showed a way using the following result:

Given $a$ and $b$ such that $|a| = k,$ $|b| = l$, then there is an element $c$ such that $|c| = \operatorname{lcm} (k,l)$, but I didn't understand how it works. Can someone help me please?

Comment: In general, it is hard to find primitive roots. Your professor's trick is often a good tool, but it doesn't always work. Once you've found one primitive root, it is easier to find more. Your professor's trick, in particular, won't work well for $17$, because the orders of multiplicative units there are all powers of $2$, so they'll never be relatively prime.

Comment: Yes, mr @ThomasAndrews, once $a$ is a primitive root then $a^k$ is a primitive root if $\gcd (k,|a|) = 1$, but, using his tool, how do I evaluate?

Comment: As I said, the tool doesn't really work in the case of $17$. There, however, you get a really nice result that $a$ is a primitive root if and only if $a$ is not a square modulo $17$.

Comment: An example:  work $\mod (13)$.  $3$ has order $3$, $5$ has order $4$.  Thus $15\equiv 2$ has order lcm$(3,4)=12$ so $2$ is a primitive root.

Comment: @lulu, nice touch! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any non-quadratic residue is a primitive root, since $17-1=2^4$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, can you make a answer with this argument, and in which cases it holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $p$ is a prime of the form $2^k+1$. In such a case $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ is a group with $2^k$ elements, hence every element has order $2^j$ for some $j\in[0,k]$. Assuming that $a\in\mathbb{F}_p^*$ is a quadratic non-residue:
$$ -1=\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)\equiv a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\pmod{p} $$
(the middle term is the Legendre symbol) it follows that the order of $a$ cannot be $2^{k-1}$, hence $a$ is a primitive element. In our case, $p=17$, the quadratic residues are $0,1,2,4,8,9,13,15,16$, hence every element of  $\{3,5,6,7,10,11,12,14\}$ is a primitive element $\!\!\pmod{17}$.

Comment: nice touch, I got it! Thanks.

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi: you're welcome.